Defining a finite model for proving propositional logic axiom indepencense in Isabelle
In Hilbert's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundlagen_der_Mathematik independence of propositional logic axioms is shown by defining a model for operators via truth tables, showing that some axioms are tautologies, Modus Ponens keeps tautology status and rest axioms are non-tautologies.
For example if I define the table with 2 values {F, T} where A & B is always F, and keep usual definition for implication (so MP keeps tautologies) following axioms are tautologies in the model:
(A & B)⟶A   -- (F⟶_) ≡ T
(A & B)⟶B

but the following statement is not a tautology for selected values:
A⟶B⟶(A & B)   -- (T⟶F) ≡ F, so (T⟶(T⟶F)) ≡ F

thus the statement cannot be proven with above 2 elimination axioms.
I hope truth tables could be defined via pattern matching, reducing definition size from N^2 (for binary operators), e.g. for 3 elements {F, Z, T} instead of 9 rows exhaustive truth table is defined as:
F & _ ≡ F
_ & F ≡ F
T & ?X ≡ ?X
?X & T ≡ ?X
Z & Z ≡ Z

so evaluation of tautology status could be done as a proof based on properties of a model instead of looking over a full permutations, like a formula with 4 variables and 3 values set requires evaluation of 3^4 = 81 rows.
PS Seems I'm asking for syntax to define truth tables in Isabelle and for an example of reasoning within definition of truth tables.
Maybe I define formulae and eval function and prove some properties of eval... but I don't know where to start...
